# Threejs Gltf rendering position issue

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am working in a 3D project and learning about threejs. Im able to manage rendering and manage meterial of any designed model.

Now am am facing the problem with some of mesh not rendering on it's proper position. But with the same attributes all are rendering in exact position.

I have uploaded my codebase to a Sandbox - [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-three-fiber-rendering-model-qk926r)

Only my problem with the mesh position. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Change diamond 80 on material what you like...

```
import React, { Suspense, useRef } from "react";
import { Canvas, useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber";
import {
  useGLTF,
  OrbitControls,
  Environment,
  Stage,
  Center,
  MeshRefractionMaterial,
} from "@react-three/drei";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { RGBELoader } from "three-stdlib";

const Model = ({ model, ...restProps }) => {
  const { scene, nodes } = useGLTF(model);
  const ref = useRef();

  scene.traverse((child) => {
    if (child.isMesh) {
      child.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        roughness: 0.1,
        metalness: 1,
        color: "#ffd900",
      });
    }
  });
  if (nodes.Diamond_Round_80) {
    nodes.Diamond_Round_80.visible = false;
  }

  return (
    <primitive object={scene} ref={ref} {...restProps}>
      <mesh
        position={[0, 0, 14.8]}
        scale={0.67}
        geometry={nodes.Diamond_Round_80.geometry}
      >
        <MeshRefractionMaterial envMap={restProps.envMap} toneMapped={false} />
      </mesh>
    </primitive>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const hdrTexture = useLoader(RGBELoader, "/hdr/aerodynamics_workshop_1k.hdr");
  hdrTexture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        height: "100vh",
      }}
    >
      <Canvas>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Stage preset="rembrandt" environment="city">
            <OrbitControls />
            <color attach="background" args={["#FFFFFF"]} />
            <Center>
              <Model model="/models/amit_trial.gltf" envMap={hdrTexture} />
            </Center>

            <Environment
              map={hdrTexture}
              files={"/models/aerodynamics_workshop_1k.hdr"}
              background="#FFFFFF"
            />
          </Stage>
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Łukasz D. Mastalerz. I  have tried with the same code, but the problem is that I want to implement @react-three/drei's MeshRefractionMaterial for gems and the then unable to implement. Could you please help me to use MeshRefractionMaterial on your same code?

Comment: Check updating code

Comment: That's correct but I need to apply @react-three/drei's MeshRefractionMaterial in to scene.traverse. How to do this?

Comment: Check update code, now is ok, but this solution is very... acrobatic. I couldn't figure out in r3f how replace original only Diamond because that material is not "classic". Probably someone smarter and more familiar with syntax would make that better. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-three-fiber-rendering-model-forked-fpxswq?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A34%2C12

Comment: It's not possible to set position and scale for every mesh manually. Thanks for your valuable response. - @Łukasz D. Mastalerz